# How to dereference an std::map member pointer inside a class?

Tags: c++

I'm currently learning C++ and ran across this that has me stumped.
I have this class:

```
class MyClass {
  public:      
    std::map<int,int> *myMaps;
}
```

How do I dereference myMaps? This does not work.

```
int main() {
  MyClass *test = new MyClass();
  std::map<int,int> *testMap = new std::map<int,int>();
  (*testMap)[1] = 1;

  test->myMaps = testMap;
  std::cout << *test->myMaps[1] << std::endl;
```

As a follow up, what if I had a std map inside a map and how to dereference that?

```
class MyClass {
  public:      
    std::map<int,std::maps<int,int>> *myMaps;
}
```

Comment: Need brackets to enforce precedence. Just like you did when dereferencing the testMap

Comment: Is there a good reason why `myMaps` is a pointer?  I can't think of any.  This looks like something that Java programmers do when they start writing C++.

Comment: `(*test->myMaps)[1]`, exactly the same pattern you used above. BTW, make sure to run it with `valgrind` and fix all the errors. You are leaking memory all over the place. `new` without `delete` is a recipe for tears and, in a way, so are both of them combined. Either nest `myMaps` directly into `MyClass`, no need for explicit dynamic allocation, or, if you insist on dynamically allocating an STL container (which is an antipattern), please use `std::unique_ptr<std::map<int, int>>`. Your future self will thank you and `valgrind` will praise you.

Comment: Another side note: Why not `std::map<int,int> myMaps;` in `MyClass` and then, in `main()`, `std::map<int,int> testMap; testMap[1] = 1; test->myMaps = std::move(testMap);`? Avoid raw pointers; you don’t need them in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I dereference `myMaps`?

The same way you dereference any other pointer.  Exactly as you are doing in `(*testMap)[1] = 1;`

> This does not work.

No, it doesn't, but this does:

```cpp
test->myMaps = testMap;

std::cout << (*(test->myMaps))[1] << std::endl;
// or cleaner:
// std::cout << (*test->myMaps)[1] << std::endl;
// due to operator precedence...
```

Note the extra parenthesis around the pointer before invoking `map::operator[]` on the dereferenced `std::map` object.

> As a follow up, what if I had a std map inside a map and how to dereference that?

First you dereference `myMaps`, as shown above, then you access the inner map by key, exactly the same way you access any value by key, eg:

```cpp
(*(test->myMaps))[1][2] = ...;
//(*test->myMaps)[1][2] = ...;

cout << (*(test->myMaps))[1][2];`
//cout << (*test->myMaps)[1][2];`
```

---

That being said, there is no good reason to use a pointer to a `std::map` at all.  Use this instead:

```cpp
class MyClass {
  public:      
    std::map<int,int> myMaps;
};

int main() {
  MyClass test;
  std::map<int,int> testMap;
  testMap[1] = 1;

  test.myMaps = std::move(testMap);
  // or, prior to C++11:
  // test.myMaps.swap(testMap);

  std::cout << test.myMaps[1] << std::endl;
}
```

```cpp
class MyClass {
  public:      
    std::map<int,std::map<int,int>> myMaps;
};

int main() {
  MyClass test;
  std::map<int,std::map<int,int>> testMap;
  testMap[1][2] = 1;

  test.myMaps = std::move(testMap);
  // test.myMaps.swap(testMap);

  std::cout << test.myMaps[1][2] << std::endl;
}
```